# if condition in the for loop

Tags: c

This program outputs 1. I could not understand how it outputs 1 as the for loop will fail at `a[2][3]` which contains the value 12. So 12 will get assigned to k and the output will have to be 12.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[3][4]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
    int i,j,k=99;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            if(a[i][j]<k)
            {
                k=a[i][j];
                printf("%d\n",k);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Res:%d\n",k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: a[i][j] with i == 0 and j == 0 equals 1, and 1 is < 99 so it outputs 1

Comment: @Beata: have you *ever* tried to run your programs in a debugger?

Comment: @yi_H: Sorry i didnt try in debugger. I'm using visual studio.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Debugger

Comment: will try with visual studio debugger.Thanks.

Comment: This is a typical function to find the minimum, so 1 is correct. To find the maximum, assign to `k` if `a[i][j] > k` and start with `k = MIN_INT;` or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time through the loop the if is evaluated as a[0][0] < k which is 1 < 99 which is true.
The second time through he loop if the if is a[1][0] < k which is 2 < 1 which evaluates as false thus the value of k is not updated
k is never reassigned another value, thus at the end k=1.

Answer (score 1):

In this line you are changing the K value

> k=a[i][j];

And the first itteration you run would change k to 1, that's why the second itteration would fail. On every itteration your k would be one unit less than it should be for if statement to work

Answer (score 1):

Some comments:

Calling a variable `k` tells us nothing about what you are using it for.  Had you called it `arrayMin` then it would have been clearer to us.  Using `i` and `j` for loop indexes is fine, that is expected.

Assigning `k=99` makes assumptions about the contents of the array and hence makes for fragile code.  Better not to make assumptions and to start by assigning `arrayMin = a[0][0]`

Your program is small and simple enough that you could run through it yourself on paper.  Doing that would have helped you see what was going on.  Using a debugger to single-step through it would have helped as well.

Comment: Sorry.. will try to solve simple examples myself on paper from here after.